# section without numbering, and text follow right after the section title

Tags: titlesec, sections-paragraphs

Anyone can tell me how to make such a section style:
[image]

I searched internet and kind of know I need to do it with \titlesec package. But I can not find a way to both remove the numbering in front of the section and make the text follow the section title in the same line.

Comment: Is `\section*{}` what you want? Or maybe `\subsection*{}`

Comment: Change font is another question.

Comment: Probably use `\paragraph{}`, especially if it is only such a short text segment? You may want to use `titlesec` to add the fullstop though.

Answer (score 3):

```
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[runin]{\sffamily\bfseries\Large}{}{0pt}{}
```

should do more or less what you want for unnumbered sections.

*Edit*: A full minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[runin]
  {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Fundings.}Israeli Centers for Research Excellence (I-CORE); Israeli Ministry of Science (712845); Crown Photonic Center.

\section*{Acknowledgements.}We thank Dekel Ra’anan and Ronen Chriki for their fruitful insights and Nitzan Artzi for his help with the learning algorithms.

\end{document}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

*Update*:

Having looked at the code in `optica.cls`,  it appears it relies on the `titlesec` package, with the `[explicit]` option. So you may try this code in your preamble

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[runin]
  {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {#1} }%
```

[]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mbKG.png

Comment: I think your solution should in principle work, but I tried and I still get number in front of the title, and the paragraph didn't start right after the title. I guess the problem is the document class I used (\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{optica}) try to overwrite the \section style somehow.

Comment: Did you use the `\section`or  the `\section*` command?

Comment: I used \section, let me try the other one now.

Comment: Tested, both \section and \section* do not work.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of the exact code you use, or a link to such an example?

Comment: Hi Bernard, here is the link to the journal template:https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-preparing-an-article-for-submission-to-optica/gmsbdqxbmntw#.Ww2UtJArJaR

Comment: @ZoneThin: Unfortunately, I do  not have access to the `optica.cls` file, to see what's in it. Do you have it? Just in case: maybe trying with `titleformat{...}` just after `\begin{document}` might work.

Comment: I thought you can get the file from that link. Anyway, I uploaded this cls file to here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YYrdOxTavN24K7KI3QGGWbQHo5q89SbD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ZoneThin: It seems it couldn't work because `optica.cls` already loads `titlesec`; with option `explicit`. So I propose a solution adapted to this option. Hopefully, it should work. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I already used the solution I offered below, and submitted the paper. But I think your answer will be beneficial for other people who want to submit short paper to OPTICA.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for contributing, guys. In the end I give up using \section command, instead used following code to walk around the problem:

```
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent\textbf{\LARGE{Fundings.}} test1
\vspace{\baselineskip}


\noindent\textbf{\LARGE{Acknowledgments.}} test2
\vspace{\baselineskip}
```

I think it will be enough for someone who want to write a paper in latex to implement the style I pasted in the question, and don't have much time to waste on learning the 24 pages manual of titlesec package. And the truth is I spent a lot of time reading that manual, and still didn't find a way.